# Angular2 - pass data to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the accordion component (simplified)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'accordion-section',
    template: `<div class='accordion' [ngClass]="{'ng-dirty': formDirty}"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})
export class AccordionSectionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    formDirty: boolean = false;
}
```

Based on *formDirty* I add class in a template.

Inside accordion I have a form component which emits *dirty* event when any field change.

```
export class NetworkInterfaceForm implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            ...
        });

        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
            this.dirty.emit(true);
        })
    }
}
```

And parent (to accordion) component html which binds everything

```
<accordion-section title="Network Interface Settings" #id1>
    <network-interface-form (dirty)="id1.formDirty = $event"></network-interface-form>
</accordion-section>
```

Currently it works. How can I bind those components without usage of `#id1` ?

Comment: You can use a shared service ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I know but I don't want to as there will be many accordions and forms. Besides later accordion will be used as library component in other applications.